# Custom glibc in non-standard path on machine with uclibc and gcc compiled against uclibc

Tags: c, gcc, glibc, limits, uclibc

I have machine with uClibc, and I've managed to get glibc work on it using a simple wrapper I made.

It can compile simple programs like hello world, and almost any other c program.

But, it doesn't compile most of gnu and others programs because of following error, when they include limits.h

```
In file included from /usr/glibc/include/limits.h:123:0,
                 from test.c:1:
/usr/lib/gcc/mips-openwrt-linux-uclibc/4.8.3/include/limits.h:125:26: error: no include path in which to search for limits.h
 # include_next <limits.h>
```

What do I need to do to resolve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

If someone needs it - I found how to get it work. You need to remove gcc's limits.h and rename gsyslimits.h to limits.h and edit glibc's limits.h, remove macros for defining if gcc header limits.h is used. If someone need - I can post complete both limits.h.
Sorry for my English. I'm Russian